# Passing navigator object to components with React Navigator and expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native app, where I want to do a redirect on a certain component.

I have a main `App.js` component, where I have the following source code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import styles from "./assets/styles";
import HomeScreen from "./containers/Home";
import MatchesScreen from "./containers/Matches";
import MessagesScreen from "./containers/Messages";
import ProfileScreen from "./containers/Profile";
import Icon from "./components/Icon";
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const App = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        Explore: {
            screen: HomeScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                    return (
                        <Text style={styles.iconMenu}>
                            <Ionicons name="md-add-circle" size={30} color={focused ? 'purple': 'black'} />
                        </Text>
                    );
                }
            }
        },
        Matches: {
            screen: MatchesScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                    return (
                        <Text style={styles.iconMenu}>
                <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={30} color={focused ? 'purple': 'black'} />
                        </Text>
                    );
                }
            }
        },
        Chat: {
            screen: MessagesScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                    return (
                        <Text style={styles.iconMenu}>
                            <Ionicons name="md-checkmark" size={30} color={focused ? 'purple': 'black'} />
                        </Text>
                    );
                }
            }
        },
        Profile: {
            screen: ProfileScreen,
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                    return (
                        <Text style={styles.iconMenu}>
                        <Ionicons name="md-ac-unit" size={30} color={focused ? 'purple': 'black'} />
                        </Text>
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: "#7444C0",
            inactiveTintColor: "#363636",
            labelStyle: {
                fontSize: 14,
                textTransform: "uppercase",
                paddingTop: 10
            },
            style: {
                backgroundColor: "#FFF",
                borderTopWidth: 0,
                paddingVertical: 30,
                height: 60,
                marginBottom: 0,
                shadowOpacity: 0.05,
                shadowRadius: 10,
                shadowColor: "#000",
                shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 }
            }
        }
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(App);
```

I want to be able to navigate from each of the rendered screens. 
I have tried adding the navigator object to the component, but I don't know how to pass it or make a propper navigation pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-navigation pass the navigation props into its child component (your HomeScreen, MatchesScreen, ... should have the navigation props) and when you want to navigate to the other screen, you can use `navigation.navigate(screenName)`

For example:

```js
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <View>
    <Text>Home</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigtate('Matches')}>
      <Text>Go to Matches</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigtate('Chat')}>
      <Text>Go to Chat</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
)
```